# Issue with gist indentation

Tags: github, gist

When creating a Gist on Github there is a setting for indentation (tabs or spaces; size 2, 4, or 8). After setting indents to tabs size 4, it changes to tabs size 8 after I save it. Editing it afterwords doesn't do anything. Other settings don't produce the expected result either. Am I misunderstanding this feature somehow? Can't find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Im getting the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not :/

Comment: I'm getting the same issue :(

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I think you found a bug! Let the good folks at support@github.com know about it!

Comment: quite annoying I must admit, same issue, if it is not a bug then it is a missing feature that should align to user preferences accordingly (which is not the case as we see).

Answer (score 1):

I replaced tabs with four spaces in Notepad++ (Ctrl+H), and it works. You can use any numbers of spaces.

Those tabs are automatically displayed as a 8-character-tab in Github Gist.

Comment: Yeap, works, changed my .editorconfig setup to use spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because while writing the code, you used the tab key which inserted 8 spaces. Here's a solution that I use.

1. Copy all your code to a local file and open it in the vi editor.
   `cat>temp.js`
   `ctrl+shift+v` to paste and `ctrl+d` to save.

   `vim temp.js` (Or change the extension as per your file.)
2. Run the following command that I found from [here](https://gist.github.com/ericdouglas/72621cb47b368297feaa). This will half the existing space.

   `:%s;^\(\s\+\);\=repeat(' ', len(submatch(0))/2);g`
3. Press the `esc` key then `:x` and `enter` key to save and exit vi.
4. Copy the code in your temp.js file and paste it in your gist with spaces as 4.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the indentation from ***Tabs to Spaces*** or ***Spaces to Tabs*** by using [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) with the easy and simple following steps.

1. Open the file with vscode.
2. Press,

   - On MacOS, <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
   - On Windows, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
3. Type *"convert indentation to spaces"* and select then option. *(As shown in the below fig)*
4. Save the file. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While creating the gist, that setting is indeed broken. Github says this is by design, LOL.

Luckily, there’s another setting in the account preferences, which does work.
That setting is “Tab size preference” on the following page: https://github.com/settings/appearance

The default value is 8. The setting applies globally, and it also affects the gists you view while logged in.